# jQuery scaling effects, scale in 1.1 and back to 1 when background position changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried the CSS route but all new to me and learning still but cannot seem to work it out. My JS below switches the background position to show a new image in the sprite every 1 second but wondering if anyone knew how I can kind of give it a small scale effects so when it changes grows a little then back to normal size before change to the next background position?

JS:

```
    // Avatar animations
var avatarInterval;
function startAvatarAnimation() {

    var i = 0;
    var avatarSpeed = 500;
    var avatarCount= 11;
    var avatarHeight = 250;
    var avatarTotalHeight = 2750;

    avatarInterval = setInterval(function(){
        i++;
        if(i > 11){
            i = 0;
        }
        $(".avatars").css({'background-position' : '0 -' + (i*avatarHeight) + 'px' });
        $(".avatars").toggleClass('scaleIn', 'scaleOut');
    }, avatarSpeed);

    return false;

}

function stopAvatarAnimation(){
    clearInterval(avatarInterval); 
    $(".avatars").css({'background-position' : '0 0' });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JS below switches the background position to show a new image in the
>   sprite every 1 second but wondering if anyone knew how i can kind of
>   give it a small scale effects so when it changes grows a little then
>   back to normal size before change to the next background position?

Try utilizing `transition` at `css` , setting duration to half of `avatarSpeed` or half of total duration of `background-position` effect ; setting `transitionend` event at `.one()` to prevent recursive call to `transitionend` handler , `.removeClass()` , `.addClass()` to toggle scale effect defined at `css`

css

```
.avatars {
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(/path/to/background-image);
}
.avatars.scaleIn {
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
.avatars.scaleOut {
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

js

```
// Avatar animations
var avatarInterval;
function startAvatarAnimation() {

    var i = 0;
    var avatarSpeed = 500;
    var avatarCount= 11;
    var avatarHeight = 250;
    var avatarTotalHeight = 2750;

    avatarInterval = setInterval(function(){
        i++;
        if(i > 11){
            i = 0;
        }
        $(".avatars").css({'background-position' : '0 -' + (i*avatarHeight) + 'px' })
        .removeClass("scaleOut").addClass("scaleIn")
        .one("transitionend", function() {
          $(this).removeClass("scaleIn").addClass("scaleOut");
        });
    }, avatarSpeed);

    return false;

}
```

```js
$(".avatars").on("click", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("scaleOut").addClass("scaleIn")
    .one("transitionend", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("scaleIn").addClass("scaleOut");
  })
})
```

```css
.avatars {
  transition: transform 500ms ease-in-out;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature);
}
.avatars.scaleIn {
  transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
.avatars.scaleOut {
  transform: scale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="avatars"></div>
```